# Copying file using DocumentsContract throws IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-studio, storage-access-framework

I am trying to copy a file in the internal storage to my app Directory using the storage acces Framework. However when i try to copy a file it throws:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URI: file:///sdcard/Android/data/com.kpwnapps.pmmpplugins/files/PocketMine-MP/plugins
```

This is the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {


        if(requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                try {
                    DocumentsContract.copyDocument(getContentResolver(),data.getData(),Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/Android/data/com.kpwnapps.pmmpplugins/files/PocketMine-MP/plugins")));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("copy",e.toString());
                }
            }


        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps instead of using a hardcoded URI for the SDCard access, you should use https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getExternalFilesDirs(java.lang.String), to get the correct files and paths. You can scroll and see more details on how to see if the External storages are removable storages etc.

Comment: You cannot use a `file://` uri. Need a `content://` uri i think.

Comment: I have used `content://` but that does not work @blackapps

Comment: Where did you use that? You did not replace file:// with content:// did you? You did not make something like content:///sdcard/Android..... did you?

Comment: I used `Uri.parse("content:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.kpwnapps.pmmpplugins/files/PocketMine-MP/plugins")` @blackapps

Comment: As you could already conclude from my last comment that is not the way to go. Have a look at the value of data.getData().toString() to see how a content uri looks like. Then use a saf uri for the destination directory.